# How long can a battery last with a maintainer?

Tags: battery

How long can a 600 CCA battery last with a maintainer on it and gentle, weekly use of car.

This is a 2011 Grand Sport with battery in trunk. The maintainer would be running 24/7.

Comment: The maintainer is a battery charger, not a life extender. The battery can, and will, fail at the end of its useful life.

Comment: If you're driving it why would you need a maintainer?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state a "Grand Sport" ... are you talking a Corvette? Something else?

Comment: Depends on the quality of the battery being maintained.

Comment: Interstate battery w/ Battery Tender 20 amp maintainer

Answer (score 3):

As Solar Mike stated, the maintainer is not a miracle worker. It's just a specialized charger which will help keep the battery in tip-top shape while a car sits. The normal lifespan of a regular battery is around 5 years. While a maintainer (or *tender*, if you like) won't extend the life of the battery, it should allow you to get the full lifespan of the battery. Plus, the battery will be completely charged when you go to start the vehicle. It will also prevent sulfation on the plates inside the battery due to the battery getting run down after sitting for a long period of time. This is a particular killer of batteries which aren't getting used regularly.

Battery tenders are a cheap investment for keeping your battery working well, especially when the battery sits a lot (months on end). If you are regularly running the vehicle, there shouldn't be a huge issue or worry. If there's a chance the vehicle is going to be sitting for an extended period of time (over several months), the maintainer/tender is going to do it's business and keep the battery ready to start your car when you want to start it.

Comment: Interstate battery w/ Battery Tender 20 amp maintainer  on 2011 Corvette G.S.